# How to set the title of a book in the References in an upright font shape

Tags: bibtex, formatting

I am trying to set the book title style to plain in `namedplus.bst` but don't seem to be able to. Currently this is what I have

```
FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title emphasize
}
```

and replacing it with the following code from another style file that gives plain text format for the title gives me error messages

```
FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
    }
  if$
}
```

error message: 
the literal stack isn't empty for entry

could you please help me with this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).

Comment: To understand what is going on, we would need to know what `bibinfo.check` does. But have you tried simply deleting the `emphasize` in the `format.btitle` function?

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the `emphasize`:

```
FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title
}
```

The checks you copied are unnecessary, as the formatted title is checked in different places.

Answer (score 1):

The function `emphasize` in the file `namedplus.bst` is defined as follows:

```
FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\em " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

- I recommend you first create a function called, say, `plain`, to be placed right after the `emphasize` function, which mimics all aspects of the `emphasize` function except that it skips the `\em` directive:

  ```
  FUNCTION {plain}
  { duplicate$ empty$
      { pop$ "" }
      { "{" swap$ * "}" * }
    if$
  }
  ```

  Upon reflection, the line `{ "{" swap$ * "}" * }` doesn't do anything at all, and hence the function `plain` may be simplified to:

  ```
  FUNCTION {plain}
  { duplicate$ empty$
      { pop$ "" }
      { }
    if$
  }
  ```
- Second, replace the instruction `title emphasize` in the `format.btitle` function with

  ```
  title plain
  ```
- Finally, be sure to save the file under a new name, e.g., `mynamedplus.bst` and to provide the instruction

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{mynamedplus}
  ```

  in your TeX document to start using the modified bibliography style.

Comment: Won't work. You replace the title with an empty string.

Comment: @mafp - Please see the corrected version.

Comment: OK, now it will work. But it is really pedantic. E.g., the braces you add around the title are superfluous. If you remove that, your `plain` function boils down to an `empty$` check, and then the title is left on the stack. But then the `empty$` check is superfluous, as the check was in `emphasize` to make sure there are strings to be concatenated, and the real check that can produce user warnings happens elsewhere. If you remove that check too, the function boils down to `FUNCTION {plain}{}`, which should not be in any `bst` file. The advice to make the changes transparent is good, though.

Comment: @mafp -- I guess I don't see the need to dispense with the both the `duplicate$` and `empty$` checks when executing the call to "print" the book's title.

Comment: When the title is actually printed via `output.check` or its variants, the check is fine, and will generate a visible `warning$`. But look what your `plain` function does now: if the literal on the stack is empty, it is popped, and a new empty string is put on the stack (Why?). If the literal is not empty, the function does nothing. Basically, your function does nothing than burning electricity ;-) That's why I said that your function is equivalent to `FUNCTION {plain}{}` *under all circumstances*.